# is that possible to add one person from multiple calls in twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, conference

I am developing an application,which is first make a voice  call to the all the customers  simultaneously.but call will connect to the only one person first who picks the call.later we wanted to add third person into the conference.is it possible in twilio voice call?
i already did call to multiple users at a time and trying to add one person into the conference but it is connecting the call to the all the users.how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. If you use the below technique, keep in mind the first dialed party to pick up (including voicemail) gets the call and all other call legs are cancelled.

The [Connect Call To Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call), Connect to multiple numbers, in Twilio Studio can also do this.

[Dialing Multiple Numbers Simultaneously with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html)

Comment: thank yoy Alan,but it is not working as we expected.it is adding all the calls into the conference while making simultaneously calls to the all clients.how i want is.Client A make a calls to Client B,C,D,E simultaneously if one of them picks a call we have to end up a call to remaining of them.later we if we want to add Client X we can add them into a conference call.like this i have to do.but the thing is it is adding all clients who picks the call they are come to the call.for example if Client B,C,D,E picks call they all are coming into the call with a Client A

Comment: It is really difficult to offer any insight without a diagram and what Twilio API's/TwiML you are uing. Are you using Agent Conference (Create Participant) to make all the outbound calls, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691853/how-to-make-a-call-to-multiple-clients-and-how-to-add-one-of-them-into-conferenc for my issue